# How to animate the jquery ajax result instead of it jumping in

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-animate

I have a bar, that when you click on it, it slides down and shows a spinner, then an ajax call gets fired and the result replaces the spinner to show that it is done.

The problem I have is the data is taller than the spinner, so it slides down and shows the spinner, but then jumps down and shows the ajax result.

How can I animate the ajax?

```
if(clicked_elem_lev == anslev){
    // Kick off ajax request for level information
    $.ajax({
        url:  base_url + "ajax/return_level_info/" + ccode + "/" + clicked_rec_id,
        cache: false
        }).done(function( html ) {
        $("#childof_" + anslevel + "_" + clicked_rec_id).replaceWith(html);
    });
}
```

The other code is all dynamic so if difficult to show but heres the slide JS

```
$('#' + targ_elem_id).slideDown(slidetime);
```

Comment: Have you considered using CSS to hide the AJAX content, and then using jQuery to animate it in using the `done()` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `slideDown()` method or `animate` references:

http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_slidedown.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_animate.asp

http://api.jquery.com/animate/